# How to use dispatch in a class component or how to refacter my HOC

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, higher-order-components

I'm having the following HOC component which is working fine but It's giving me an error on the dispatch. I can't use it inside a class component but how do I fix this?

```
const withAuthentication = <Props extends object>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
) => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component<Props & FirebaseInterface> {
    render(): React.ReactNode {
      const { firebase, ...props } = this.props
      const dispatch = useDispatch()
      const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false)
      const { userId, loggedIn } = useSelector(
        (state: Record<string, ReduxProvider>) => state.user
      )

      useEffect(() => {
        const listener = firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
          if (authUser) {
            console.log(authUser)
            if (!loggedIn) {
              firebase.user(userId).once('value', snapshot => {
                dispatch(
              )
              })
            }

            setAuthenticated(true)
          } else {
            dispatch(
              addUser({

              })
            )

            setAuthenticated(false)
          }
        })

        return (): void => {
          listener()
        }
      }, [setAuthenticated, firebase, dispatch, loggedIn, userId])
    }
  }

  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication)
}

export default withAuthentication
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have your `import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'` at the top?

Can you also share the error you are getting.

Comment: Hi @snoopy, yes I have the import! The error is that I can't use a hook in a non functional component. So can't use it a class component like I'm currently doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use useDispatch in class component.

You should use import.

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {compose} from 'redux'

...
const {dispatch} = this.props
...
return compose(withFirebase, connect(state => ({}), dispatch => ({dispatch})) )(WithAuthentication)
...

...
```